# customizing facebook like informations displaying in profile facebook pages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have to customize the elements displayed in the facebook personal page after publishing the like made to a post on a website.

I see that image, title and links are displayed but i have to display the post description too.

I've read, following some "Questions that may..." that i should use the Open Graph API but i would do the simplest solution ever to include the "description". If i could use the basic solutions offered by Facebook it would be a better solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the Open Graph API headers in the HTML page of your posts. E.g. in any post page from your website you have to add something like this in your HEAD section

```
    <meta property="og:type"        content="website" />
    <meta property="og:site_name"   content="Site name" />
    <meta property="og:title"       content="Title" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Some description" />
    <meta property="og:image"       content="..." />
```

Comment: So i can use directly this + the predefined like box or i have to initialize the app and then pass these meta?

Comment: These have to be in the HEAD section of the specific "post on a website", the one that is being liked. When a "Like" is clicked FB tries to parse/examine the url that is associated with this Like button. And if it finds such meta tags in it then FB can represent it on the user's wall more "pleasantly", e.g. showing the specified image, title, description and etc. So the meat tags has to be on the page that the Like button points to. (If I understand your question right)

Comment: I think it looks good. I "Liked"  the page it show nicely on my Facebook Wall. You can also use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to debug what the Facebook scrapper parses from the liked page.